# How to find all usages of name() related to specific enum type

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, structural-search

I need to find all usages of `name()` method called on specific enum type.

Let's say I've got the enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C;
}
```

I want to receive all places where the method is called on any of `MyEnum` element. It could be called on specific elements like `A.name()`, `B.name()` and so on, but as well it could be called on a parameter or a iterating variable, for example:

```
String myMethod(MyEnum myEnum) {
    return myEnum.name();
}
```

So far I could do it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> on each element of `MyEnum` and the enum type itself and then look for occurences containing `name()` call in results. But this require a lot of manual work.

The other approach I've tried was to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> having cursor over method's name in statement like `A.name()` but it found all occurences of `name()` called on **any** enum type.

So is it possible to do this easier and faster?

Comment: Faster?  Starting with a clean build, rename the enum class without updating references, and all compile issues will be references to the enum class.

Comment: @AndrewS _all compile issues_ - I didn't need **all** of them. This wouldn't be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In structural search (Edit > Find > Search structurally...), search for:

```
$e$.name()
```

then hit "Edit Variables...", select `e`, and set the "Expression type (regexp)" to be the enum you are interested in.

(Remember that any reference of type `Enum<?>`  could contain a reference to a `MyEnum`, so you may need to consider looking for those also)